# How can I save radio button options in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have created 2 custom radio buttons and created labels with each of them, male and female. I want to save whichever option the user selects in core data.

In core data I have already created on entity and have added an attribute of gender, but what "type" should I select? A string, boolean, number etc.?

Also how can I add the selected radio button type in core data?

Comment: just you take bool variable for that ... if male then 1 and female then 0.

Comment: when creating the btns I set the tags 0 and 1, and this is how they are being deleted based on the tags but I want to store them in core data just I have stored data entered by user in text field. From what I understand, you are saying that instead of creating an attribute gender, I should simply create 2 attributes male and female and set the type to bool?

Comment: The buttons and what you store don't have to be the same thing - Your Core Data entity is your data model.  You could store a string "male/female", you could store a BOOL (male=YES, female=NO), you could store an int - "1=Male, 2=Female, 3=Cat..." it doesn't matter.  When you initialise your view (i.e. the buttons) you need to interpret the data to set the state of the buttons - Similarly when the buttons are changed by the user, store the appropriate  value in your entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add Boolean in your core data schema; and add your radio button's state into it.

Comment: So, I have to create 2 attributes male and female, each with type bool?

Comment: Not really, just add 1 attribute, On isMale, is its true then its a male, if its false, then its a female.
You good also make a string type attribute; save either male or female in it, but I would go with first approach.

Comment: okay thanks....I getting a hold of it. One more question....for now I am storing it as bool, but when the user enters data, it should get saved to core data and display the desired selected radio button ,male or female, in a new label. How ca I save bool value as label text?

Comment: When you retrieve the boolean from coredata, do something like this:
if (isMale) 
label.text = @"Male"; 
else 
label.text = @"Female";

Comment: Hi, I have another situation to this. I have a 5 radio buttons (for example 5 tel numbers and need to choose one "Default"). So is there a way to make a YES exclusive within a group of objects with a boolean property, where setting the boolean of one object to YES automatically switches it to NO for all other objects?

Comment: Not really, but you could do this, just save the radio button with true, In code you assume all the radio button are false except the one you saved.

Comment: hmm.... Could you please explain me how to do this. I'm newbie in Core Data :(

Comment: Tell me, which options are you using for radio button?

Comment: Simple radio button, its added to NSTableCellView in tableview.
Nothing special.

Comment: I mean what is the model behind the radio button? age, rating etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107730/discussion-between-kroumvud-and-abubakr-dar).